# How is this cache manager storing the cached data?

Tags: c#, caching, concurrentdictionary

I am using [this cache manager, taken from bbarry on github](https://gist.github.com/bbarry/3301a9277742c6a76236).

I don't understand where or how the cached data is actually being stored.  Most caching I've seen uses `MemoryCache`, but I don't see a mention of this anywhere.

I can only think that the `ConcurrentDictionary` is storing the cached data, but if so, I don't understand why this is a set to `readonly`.

```
public static class Cache<T> {
    static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, T> Dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, T>();

    //by making this a tuple with the generic constraint, there will be one per cache type; the first parameter will always be the default value
    static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<T, DateTime, TimeSpan>> Removals = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<T, DateTime, TimeSpan>>();


    public static T GetOrAdd(string key, Func<string, T> creator) { return GetOrAdd(key, creator, null, null); }


    public static T GetOrAdd(string key, Func<string, T> creator, DateTime absoluteExpiration) { return GetOrAdd(key, creator, absoluteExpiration, null); }


    public static T GetOrAdd(string key, Func<string, T> creator, TimeSpan slidingExpiration) { return GetOrAdd(key, creator, null, slidingExpiration); }


    public static bool TryGetValue(string key, out T value) {
        Tuple<T, DateTime, TimeSpan> when;
        if (Removals.TryGetValue(key, out when) && when.Item3 != TimeSpan.Zero) {
            Remove(key, Tuple.Create(default(T), DateTime.Now.Add(when.Item3), when.Item3));
        }
        return Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value); 
    }


    public static bool Expire(string key, out T value) { return Dictionary.TryRemove(key, out value); }


    public static void Expire(string key) {
        T value;
        Dictionary.TryRemove(key, out value);
    }

    static T GetOrAdd(string key, Func<string, T> creator, DateTime? absoluteExpiration, TimeSpan? slidingExpiration) {
        if (key == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        }
        Tuple<T, DateTime, TimeSpan> when;
        var updateRemoval = Removals.TryGetValue(key, out when) && when.Item3 != TimeSpan.Zero;
        var v = Dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, creator);
        if (absoluteExpiration == null && slidingExpiration == null && !updateRemoval) {
            return v;
        }
        if (absoluteExpiration != null || slidingExpiration != null) {
            var expiration = (TimeSpan)(slidingExpiration ?? (absoluteExpiration - DateTime.Now));
            when = Tuple.Create(default(T), DateTime.Now.Add(expiration), expiration);
        } else {
            when = Tuple.Create(default(T), DateTime.Now.Add(when.Item3), when.Item3);
        }
        if (absoluteExpiration != null) {
            Removals.TryAdd(key, Tuple.Create(default(T), (DateTime)absoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.Zero));
        } else {
            Removals.AddOrUpdate(key, when, (a, b) => when);
        }

        Remove(key, when);
        return v;
    }

    static void Remove(string key, Tuple<T, DateTime, TimeSpan> then) {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(then.Item3).ContinueWith(task => {
            Tuple<T, DateTime, TimeSpan> when;
            if (!Removals.TryGetValue(key, out when) || when.Item2 >= DateTime.Now)
                return;
            T v;
            Dictionary.TryRemove(key, out v);
            Removals.TryRemove(key, out when);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`readonly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) modifier doesn't mean that you can't modify a collection which was marked with it (`ConcurrentDictionary<string, T> Dictionary` in this case).

It only means that you can't reassign its value. So in this example you can't do

```
Dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, T>();
```

again. The documentation for `readonly` (linked above) lists the possible places where a field marked as `readonly` can be assigned. In constructor or static constructor or field declaration.

And the answer to your question is yes, it's the `ConcurrentDictionary` which stores the data in this case. ([`GetOrAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx) method).

Comment: Nice one Szabolcs, thanks for explaining and clarifying :)